# How can i flip the the axis of this bar chart in flutter syncfusion

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, syncfusion

I don't know what I am doing wrong with syncfusion chart but I want the days of the week to be don't the x-axis and the numbers on the y-axis but even though I exchanged the values of xValueMapper and yValueMapper I get errors. Please what can I do? this is my output[image]

and this is the code I'm using

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Charts extends StatefulWidget {
 const Charts({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
 _ChartsState createState() => _ChartsState();
}

class _ChartsState extends State<Charts> {
  late List<SalesData> _salesData;
  late TooltipBehavior _tooltipBehavior;

  @override
  void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
_salesData = getChartData();
_tooltipBehavior = TooltipBehavior(enable: true);
super.initState();
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 100),
    child: Container(
    
      child: SfCartesianChart(
        legend: Legend(isVisible: true),
        tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,
        series: <ChartSeries>[
          BarSeries<SalesData, String>(
              name: 'Sales',
              dataSource: _salesData,
              xValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.daysOfWeek,
              yValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.sale,
              dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true),
              enableTooltip: true),
        ],
        primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
        primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
            edgeLabelPlacement: EdgeLabelPlacement.shift,
            numberFormat: NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(decimalDigits: 0),
            title: AxisTitle(text: 'Sales in millions')),
      ),
    ),
     ),
   );
 }

 List<SalesData> getChartData() {
   final List<SalesData> chartData = [
     SalesData( 'Monday',1400),
     SalesData('Tuesday',600 ),
     SalesData( 'Wednesday',300),
     SalesData( 'Thursday', 600),
     SalesData(  'Friday',100),
   ];

   return chartData;
 }
 }

class SalesData {
 final daysOfWeek;
 final sale;

 SalesData(  this.daysOfWeek, this.sale);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We suspect that your requirement is to render the bar data points chart vertically along the x-axis and for this requirement, you can use the ColumnSeries available in our chart widget to render it. Please check the code snippet below for further reference.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Container(
                    child: SfCartesianChart(
                        series: <ChartSeries>[
                            // Renders column chart
                            ColumnSeries<SalesData, double>(
                                dataSource: chartData,
                                xValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.year,
                                yValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.sales
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                )      
            )
        );
}
```

For further reference on ColumnSeries and BarSeries, please refer to the user guide links below.

- https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/chart-types/column-chart
- https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/chart-types/bar-chart